# Panels are not showing on second display

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, multiple-monitors

I installed Xubuntu. Before installing it, my second monitor was displaying the panels correctly on Ubuntu.

When I installed Xubuntu, the second monitor was mirroring the primary one. I went to "Display' and unchecked the mirror option and made it appear to the right of my primary monitor.

Now the problem is that the panels on the second display are not showing while on the primary display they *are* showing.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create new panel in the primary display or move the panel from the second display to the first.

Right click on empty space on the panel and choose *Panel > Panel preferences...* Once you have that open, you can move the panels around or add new one.